# CompletableFuture chaining results

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I am trying to chain the calls/results of the methods to the next call. I get compile time error methodE because if am not able to get the reference of objB from the previous call.

How can I pass the result of the previous call to the next chain? Have I completely misunderstood the process?

```
Object objC = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.methodA(obj, width, height))
    .thenApply(objA -> {
    try {
        return service.methodB(objA);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CompletionException(e);
    }
})
   .thenApply(objA -> service.methodC(objA))
   .thenApply(objA -> {
   try {
       return service.methodD(objA); // this returns new objB how do I get it and pass to next chaining call 
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new CompletionException(e);
       }
    })
    .thenApply((objA, objB) -> {
       return service.methodE(objA, objB); // compilation error 
  })
 .get();
```

Comment: You might have your first `thenApply` return a tuple to hold both the objA and the result of methodB.  Or, since you are using `thenApply` and not `thenApplyAsync`, combining successive `thenApply` calls into one lambda is functionally equivalent and gives you the flexibility you desire

Comment: BTW, since you're using `CompletableFuture` (or `CompletionStage`), I'd replace `get()` with a completion (e.g. through `whenComplete(...)` or `handle(...)`) that would perform the last step, for instance, scheduling a future to the UI executor or generating and returning a DTO in a web service (either on sucess or on exception, reporting an error).  Avoiding blocking is usually the best "investment" compared to anything else Java's futures have to offer (although everything else is useful too).

Answer (score 14):

You could store intermediate `CompletableFuture` in a variable and then use `thenCombine`:

```
CompletableFuture<ClassA> futureA = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...)
    .thenApply(...)
    .thenApply(...);

CompletableFuture<ClassB> futureB = futureA.thenApply(...);

CompletableFuture<ClassC> futureC = futureA.thenCombine(futureB, service::methodE);

objC = futureC.join();
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use *thenCompose*, which is an asynchronous mapping, as opposed to *thenApply*, which is synchronous. Here's an example that chains two future-returning functions:

```
public CompletableFuture<String> getStringAsync() {
    return this.getIntegerAsync().thenCompose(intValue -> {
        return this.getStringAsync(intValue);
    });
}

public CompletableFuture<Integer> getIntegerAsync() {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Integer.valueOf(1));
}

public CompletableFuture<String> getStringAsync(Integer intValue) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(String.valueOf(intValue));
}
```

With *thenApply* you don't return a future. With *thenCompose*, you do.