# Async computation using CompletableFuture that returns an Object inside a for each loop

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, resttemplate, completable-future

I have a RESTFul API the response of which contains a lot of fields. I have requirement to add additional fields in the response whose values I need to fetch from an outbound RESTFul API call in an asynchronous way. The request parameters I need to call the API are contained inside a `List<A>`. During the flow of my API there is a lot of business logic involving a few DB queries and a bunch of Java Map/List Operations that happens for each iteration of my `List<A>`. So while the service does its BAU, I wanted a child thread to carry out the outbound API call, extract the information I need, set it inside object B and carry B which I will be using in my main thread towards the end of each of the iteration of my List.

Below is the code I have tried out using CompletableFuture.supplyAsync().thenApply().

```
for(A a: listA){
//at the beginning of the iteration
CompletableFuture<B> asyncB = ioSvcObject.getRequiredFields(a.getReqParam1(), a.getReqParm2())
...
The BAU goes here..
//towards the end of iteration
if(null != asyncB.get()){
 ..set data from B to response object..
}
}
```

now my ioSvcObject.getRequiredFields() method looks like this:

```
public CompletableFuture<B> getRequiredFields(String param1, String param2){
return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> getAPIResponseObj(param1, param2)).thenApply(obj -> getB(obj));

}
private D getAPIResponseObj(String param1, String param2){
//calls the API using restTemplate.exchange()
return D;
}
private B getB(D d){
//gets the required fields from d and sets it to B and returns B
return B;
}
```

Though I am hoping B to be available in asyncB before I call `asyncB.get()`, I cannot strike out the chance of ever waiting/blocking on get(). Just curious if there is a better way to do it without ever blocking. Please suggest if it can be done in a better way. Thank You.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CompletableFuture chaining results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265253/completablefuture-chaining-results)

Comment: Not really. I couldn't relate my concern with that solution.