# How to call multiple functions of different Spring beans in async

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

I am new to Async in Spring boot.

I have a bean `A` as follows:

```
 class A {
  
   private final B b;
   private final C c;

   ...
   int x = b.f();
   c.g(x);
   ...
 }
```

Here I would like to call both `f()` and `g()` in async. I have got some ideas from different articles regarding how to make `@Async` work. But, being a newbie, I cannot understand how would I call `g()` with the return value of `f()` in async.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265253/completablefuture-chaining-results

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward ,Add `@EnableAsync` annotation to a configuration class or to the main application class then add the `@Async` annotation to the method that you  want to be executed asynchronously on a separate thread. Springboot will setup a thread pool and using proxy will automatically start a new thread to handle the method call. But if you want to return something from the method then use `Future`. You can also control which thread pool to use by creating a thread pool executor bean like below and specifying it in the `@Async` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
class GeneralConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "asyncTaskExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("ScheduledTaskThread-");
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }

}

class B { 
   @Async("asyncTaskExecutor") //ask spring to use your thread pool for this async task.
   public Future<Integer> f() {
     //Do something
     return new AsyncResult<Integer>(1);
   }   
}

class C {

   @Async
   public void g() {
   //Do something
   }
}
```

From your comments, in order to wait for thee result of method f of class B to be provided as input to the method g of class C then use `CompletableFuture` like :

```
class B { 
   @Async("asyncTaskExecutor") //ask spring to use your thread pool for this async task.
   public CompletableFuture<Integer> f() {
     //Do something
     return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(1);
   }   
}
```

Then after while calling the method do something like :

```
   ...
   CompletableFuture<Integer> result = b.f();
   CompletableFuture.allOf(result).join(); //add other futures if you want to wait for other calls to complete.
   c.g(result.get());
   ...
```

Obviously there are other optimized way to use Completable Future . But it depends on how you want to use this in your code. I suggest going through the completable future docs and finding out which suits your use case best.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have one doubt. Maybe it was not clear in the OP. Actually, I would like to call g() with the return value of f() in async.  How should I do this?

Comment: @Joy You can use completable future in that case, to wait till the result is obtained and then trugger the next function with the response from the fist.

Comment: would you mind refactoring your answer accordingly?